# AttributeError: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'load'

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

I'm having difficulty with ffmpeg. I've installed it properly (I think) but still get AttributeErrors.

I used the online guide (https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), and doing `pip install ffmpeg-python` instead of `pip install ffmpeg`. I've verified the installation with `pip show`. I've also made sure to not name my files `ffmpeg.py`.

However, when I try running the following commands in terminal, I get an Attribute Error. Any tips? I've seen this question pop up before, but none of the tips have worked.

```
>>> import ffmpeg
>>> ffmpeg.load('cover.wav')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'ffmpeg' has no attribute 'load
```

Comment: Read [ffmpeg-python documentation](https://kkroening.github.io/ffmpeg-python/). The correct syntax is `input = ffmpeg.input('cover.wav')`. Why are you think `ffmpeg.load('cover.wav')` is a valid syntax?